# How do I fill only the top two courses of an existing CMU wall with grout?

Tags: masonry, grout, concrete-block

I have an existing CMU wall that is open on the top so you can see down through the holes to the bottom.  I'm going to put a beam on top of it, and the structural engineer said I need to fill the top two courses with core fill grout at the bearing points.  I've seen grout stop mesh that you can put in when building the wall, but what do I do for this existing wall?  It's ten blocks high.  If I pour in grout, it's just going to fall to the bottom.

What is the preferred method to only fill the top two courses?

Comment: Somebody will probably come along with a better/proper way of doing it, but a 2x4/steel tube with a plate on top that fits would work.  You are not holding that much weigh so even a 2x2.

Comment: they make CMUS with break out ends that for whan you want to purd a bond beam.

Comment: My preferred method is call a truck and not care that it's +$100 a yard.

Comment: @Mazura Not going to waste $100 for no good reason.

Answer (score 1):

Normally the last 2 courses would be set over blocks with the voids covered with
[Concrete block caps.](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Grip-Rite-6-5-in-x-6-5-in-Steel-Concrete-Block-Cap/50372632)

Since you have the courses set in place, you obviously need to backtrack.

Here are a few ideas:

1- Perhaps you can trim the caps to a size just a bit larger than the voids.  Then tap them into place with a 2x4.

2- Try filling the voids with cobble.

3- If you can get an extension on the tube, use spray foam to fill the void bellow the top 2 courses.  (You will need to let it set 24 hours)

4- Fill the voids from bottom to top where you will be placing the beams. ( your bearing points.) for a very strong wall.

Comment: 3: might also be able to just jam some mesh or similar down each cell.

Comment: So, I can just fill up the lower courses with a suitable material, then pour the grout on top of that?  That sounds doable.  Would sand work?  Sand is cheap, and I have lots of bags of that.

Problem is I don't want to make up my own grout, and the pre-mixed bags are in very short supply here.  I don't want to waste it all on this when I'm about to build some CMU piers for an addition that I'll be able to install the mesh properly for.

Comment: @John Long,  Yes, If you don't mind the work, just fill the lower courses with material, then use the proper grout for the final 2.

Answer (score 1):

Mesh *can* be applied to an existing wall. It's fiddly and annoying compared to putting it in when the wall was built, but it can be done.

Take a sheet bigger than the core hole, and cut in so it can be folded down with a top that fits in the core, and sides that stick down further. Then apply just a little grout, the job of which is to stick the mesh to the block. Let that cure and then fill.

An alternate method is to suspend (hang) the mesh on wires from the top. In that case probably inverted (bent parts up the sides, and they can be pretty short.) That may be a bit more certain, and there's no waiting for cure before you can fill the whole thing.